# Function setTimeout passed as argument in js class executes immediately, and call class method inside setTimeout

Tags: javascript

Js class method getInfo should call alert after 5 seconds delay, but it fires immediately

```
function limiter (limit,hid,sid) {
    this.limit = limit;
    this.hid = hid;
    this.sid = sid;


    this.getInfo = function(aca) {

       setTimeout(alert(aca), 5000);
    };
}


var limiter= new limiter(5,5,5);

limiter.getInfo("loko roko");
```

Comment: That's because you're not passing the *function* to `setTimeout()`, you're passing the result of *calling* the function. If you see `alert(aca)` in a random piece of code, what does that mean to you?

Comment: How can i then pass an argument if i write like this:   this.getInfo = setTimeout(function() {... getInfo want be function then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place the `alert` event inside a function.

```js
function limiter(limit, hid, sid) {
  this.limit = limit;
  this.hid = hid;
  this.sid = sid;
  console.log(this.limit);

  this.getInfo = function(aca) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(this.limit);
      alert(aca)
    }, 5000);
  };
}

var limiter = new limiter(5, 5, 5);

limiter.getInfo("loko roko");
```

Comment: When i call this.limit inside timeout function i get an error that this.limit is undefined
setTimeout(function() {alert(this.limit);},1000); this.start();
And i wold like to call start again

Comment: @Dime Edited my post.

Comment: I accidentally edited your post, sorry, can you write it again :/

Comment: I was trying to pass class method inside setTimeout function but it did not work. This is the solution that worked. I  added "var newclass=this;" just before setTimeout function and it worked.